# NSTimer time interval not firing correctly

Tags: swift, uibutton, nstimer

I have an  NSTimer that calls a function. The function flashes a different button each time it is called. i have the time interval set to one second and repeats is true, it stops repeating when the variable pcChoice == 10, but for some reason when i run the program it is delaying for a second and then calling the function a number of times right after each other. To the user, it looks like one second passes, then a number of buttons are flashed at once. What I need instead is for each button to flash one after another, with one second in between each flash.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    var lit = [b0o,b1o,b2o,b3o,b4o,b5o,b6o,b7o,b8o]
    var litIndex = 0

    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 1...10{
        print(randomIndex)
        print(computerChoices)

        var buttonChoice = lit[randomIndex]

        randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lit.count)))
        computerChoices[i] = randomIndex

        print("yoyoyo")

        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("flashingButtons"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}

func flashingButtons(){

    var lit = [b0o,b1o,b2o,b3o,b4o,b5o,b6o,b7o,b8o]
    one = computerChoices[pcChoice]
    lit[one].setImage(UIImage(named: "redb.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    pcChoice += 1

    if pcChoice == 10{
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating your timer 10x inside viewDidLoad ?  self.view.setNeedsDisplay() 10x inside that method makes no sense

Comment: i need it to fire multiple times, which is why i have it inside a for i loop

Comment: Mohsin fire it only once and control how many times it gets executed inside the selector method

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("flashingButtons"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

is executed 10 times because of your `for` loop. That gives you 10 different timers, each of which will invoke `flashingButtons` in about 1 second from now. Move that call out of the loop. You also don't need 10 calls to `setNeedsDisplay` in `viewDidLoad`.

Since you don't modify `lit`, make it a `let` instead of a `var`. I notice also that you have 9 elements in `lit` but you're looping through 10 times. The `lit` array in `viewDidLoad` is never used, and is different from the one in `flashingButtons`.

You could invoke `arc4random_uniform` inside `flashingButtons` each time the time fires. Or if you want the lights truly shuffled, each one being hit once, try something like this using GameplayKit:

```
let lit = [b0o,b1o,b2o,b3o,b4o,b5o,b6o,b7o,b8o]
let shuffledLit : [<lightobjects>] // whatever type of b0o, etc is

override func viewDidLoad() {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("flashingButtons"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    shuffledLit = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(lit)
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean have the random number call inside flashingButtons instead of in `viewDidLoad`? Sorry i am new to swift.